# One to many relationship mapping error with code first 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entities Task and Attempt, One task has many Attempt, so I defined the entities as below.

```
public class Task
{
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DestinationNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    // blah blah
    public virtual ICollection<Attempt> Attempts { get; set; }
}

public class Attempt
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AttemptsMetaData { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public bool Answered { get; set; }
    public DateTime Disconnected { get; set; }
    // foreign key
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

I used Code First Relationships Fluent API to map the relationship.

```
public class OutboundContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attempt> Attempts { get; set; }
    public OutboundContext()
        : base("Outbound")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OutboundContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<OutboundContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasMany(t => t.Attempts).WithRequired();
    }
```

Unit test was passed but when I check the table [Outbound].[dbo].[Attempts]. The columns are

```
   [Id]
  ,[AttemptsMetaData]
  ,[Time]
  ,[Answered]
  ,[Disconnected]
  ,[Task_TaskId]
  ,[Task_TaskId1]
```

You see first `[Task_TaskId]` is wrong and one more extra column `[Task_TaskId1]` was generated.

What is wrong?

**EDIT**:

TaskId should be the foreign key.

```
// Add dummy data
        public bool AddAttempt(List<Attempt> attempt)
        {
            using (OutboundContext db = new OutboundContext())
            {
                foreach (var item in attempt)
                {
                    db.Attempts.Add(item);
                }
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        List<Attempt> attempts = new List<Attempt>();
        Attempt objAtt = new Attempt();
        long id = 123456789;
        objAtt.AttemptId = id;
        objAtt.Time = DateTime.Now;
        objAtt.AttemptsMetaData = "test";
        objAtt.Answered = true;
        objAtt.Disconnected = DateTime.Now;
        objAtt.TaskId = 33333333;
        attempts.Add(objAtt);
        //Then call AddAttempt
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a TaskID in the code yourself (in the attempt class)? This should sort out the duplicate task_ids when you do a migration.

Comment: Yesm if you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx. It says: Code first is not able to match up the properties in the two classes on its own. The database table for Posts should have one foreign key for the CreatedBy person and one for the UpdatedBy person but code first will create four will foreign key properties: Person_Id, Person_Id1, CreatedBy_Id and UpdatedBy_Id.

Comment: We're talking the basic 1- many relationship here, I would suggest deleting your fluent API code in OnModelCreating and doing a new migration

Comment: Can I mix fluent API and DataAnnotations together?

Comment: Yes, but I think in this case, the fluent API is interfering with the code first convention. It should just work with the code first.

Comment: I removed the fluent API, and the table was created. But just can't add dummy data to it. The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Attempts_dbo.Tasks_TaskId". The conflict occurred in database "Outbound", table "dbo.Tasks", column 'TaskId'.

Comment: Right - it could be time to read up on data modelling in general. You have a foreign key to Task - so the TaskID you put in the attempt table MUST exist on the task table (as TaskID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasMany(t => t.Attempts).WithRequired(t=>t.Task).HasForeignKey(t => t.TaskId);
```

The other point is that we have to save the tables in correct order. Something like:

```
            db.Tasks.Add(task);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Attempt a = new Attempt() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), TaskId = task.TaskId, AttemptsMetaData = "1" };
            db.Attempts.Add(a);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Otherwise it shows "invalid column" on TaskId in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem happened because the Collection of Attempt you have in the Task class is not being actually referenced to the "Task" property you are having in the Attempt class. My suggestion is to clearly declare a int TaskId property in the Attempt class and do the mapping in the following way for Attempt Class:

```
HasRequired(attempt => attempt.Task)
            .WithMany(task => task.Attempts)
            .HasForeignKey(attempt => attempt.TaskId);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is incorrect. The intellisense doesn't show attempt => attempt.Task

Comment: Sorry, the syntax I provided is of EntityTypeConfiguration<T>. If you are directly dealing with OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) it should be something like : modelBuilder.Entity<Attempt>().HasRequired(attempt => attempt.Task)            .WithMany(task => task.Attempts).HasForeignKey(attempt => attempt.TaskId);

Comment: Indeed there is no Task_Id1 and the table was created. But the thing is when I add dummy data and do db.Savechanges(), An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'TaskId'.

Comment: @Love I checked your code. The problem here is that you actually need to save the Task Object and not the Attempts. As attempt is actually dependent on task, here is what you can do: add the attempts in the Task.Attempts collection and then add the task object to the context.DbSet of Task and then try saving the task object. I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: -@Sayan. Yeah, the data was inserted to the two tables. But in Task table, there is no column 'Attempt'. And also I hover over the TaskId column in SQL Server management studio. It shows "invalid column".

Comment: @Love That is how it should be right? Task and Attempt is in One To Many relationship, i.e. for one Task there are many Attempts. So Task is primary Entity and Attempt is dependent. Hence Attempt table has one TaskId column. Introducing col like AttemptId FK in Task table referencing to Attempt table will make the Task table dependent on Attempt. You can refer to this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022220.do. This is an excellent read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50962/discussion-between-love-and-sayan-pal)

Answer (score -1):

I made a very small change to the OnModelCreating and its not creating a an additional  [Task_TaskId1] in the database:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasMany(t => t.Attempts);
}
```

Comment: Please add some clarification as to how this solves the issue, with some links to relevant documentation if possible.